# Finding the last digit of certain number raised to any power

Tags: binomial-theorem

I'm trying to find the last digit of the result of any number raised to any power, using binomial theorem, not modulus or something. Please explain me why last digit of a number's unit number raised to a power is same as the original number raised to the same power using binomial theorem. 
Ex. XV^Y = V^Y

Also, I found out that each integer each its cyclicity and I understand that. But I'm confused since:
17^8 = 7^8 = 7^4 since 8 is a multiple of 4.
But why not 7^2 = 7^8 as well? 8 is also a multiple of 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the last digit that you are raising to a power several times and not about the power.

```
7^1=...7 <=
7^2=...9
7^3=...3
7^4=...1
7^5=...7 <=
7^6=...9
7^7=...3
7^8=...1
7^9=...7 <=
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a number x=t*10+u, where t is the "tens" and u is the units, so e.g. 1234=123*10+4.  The binomial theorem states: x^n = sum{k=0,...,n} (t*10)^(n-k)*u^k. As long as (n-k)>0, the summand will be a multiple of 10. You should be able to figure it out from there.